# Passing std::function type which has a templated return type

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

I have a function

```
template<typename P = int_fast16_t, typename I>
std::vector<std::vector<P>> f(
    I xb, I xe, I yb, I ye,
    std::function<P(typename std::iterator_traits<I>::value_type,
                    typename std::iterator_traits<I>::value_type)> &&score_function,
    P ID = -1, P S = -1, P M = 1)
```

It takes two pairs of iterators and a function that should compare two elements of the value_type of the iterators and returns a value of type P.

This gives me an error

```
./h.hpp:47:32: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<type-parameter-0-0 (typename iterator_traits<type-parameter-0-1>::value_type, typename iterator_traits<type-parameter-0-1>::value_type)>' against 'stringAlgorithms::scoring::plus_minus_one'
   std::vector<std::vector<P>> nw_score_matrix(I xb, I xe, I yb, I ye,
```

Now, if I change this to use the specific return type P

```
template<typename P = int_fast16_t, typename I>
   std::vector<std::vector<P>> nw_score_matrix(I xb, I xe, I yb, I ye, std::function<int_fast16_t(typename std::iterator_traits<I>::value_type, typename std::iterator_traits<I>::value_type)> &&score_function, P ID = -1, P S = -1, P M = 1)
```

this compiles.

In this case the function plus_minus_one is

```
  struct plus_minus_one {
     template<typename T, typename R = int_fast16_t>
     R operator()(const T &x, const T &y) { return x == y ? 1 : -1; }
  };
```

and passed using

```
scoring::plus_minus_one matchScoring;
```

and

```
nw_score_matrix(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), y.end(), matchScoring);
```

I realize that I could just declare a typename F in the template and make score_function a

```
F &&score_function
```

however I want to ensure that if someone creates a functor/lambda that's specific to some types that the function handles the right types. So why doesn't the declaration compile?

EDIT: a full example is found https://github.com/meconlen/stringAlgorithms/tree/soq

Comment: I don't get an error on the declaration itself: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f726666185661586

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The declaration does compile but the stuff inside the `function<...>` is a non-deduced context. Anything with `typename X<T>::type` is a non-deduced context inside a parameter declaration. You're better off with `F&&`.

Comment: You could make all the ingredient types of the `score_function` type non-deduced (e.g. `typename std::common_type<P>::type` etc.).

Comment: Nothing that is not a `std::function` (and is not derived from it) can be deduced as a `std::function`. Use something like `std::vector<std::vector<typename std::decay<typename std::result_of<F(typename std::iterator_traits<I>::value_type, typename std::iterator_traits<I>::value_type)>::type>::type>> nw_score_matrix(stuff, F&& f)`

Comment: @0x499602D2 that fixes the issue. What's happening that std::common_type<P>::type can be deduced but P can't be deduced?

Comment: A side note: `template<typename T, typename R = int_fast16_t>` will almost always use `int_fast16_t` as a return type (unless you call the operator like `matchScoring.operator()<int,int>(1, 2);`)

Comment: @MichaelConlen `P` is not deduced, it's always set to `int_fast16_t`

Comment: `std::function` is type erasure.  template functions use type pattern matching.  Type pattern matching and type erasure are opposites.  Doing both at the same time is rarely a good idea.  Why not just take an `class F` in that location?

Comment: @Yakk I'm not sure I fully appreciate what you're saying, but the issue was that I wanted to declare and ensure that score_function has the proper signature whether the caller wants a functor, lambda or whatever else a std::function might be able to encapsulate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call the function, you'll need to actually give it a `std::function`:

```
scoring::plus_minus_one matchScoring;
std::function<int_fast16_t(int,int)> score_function = matchScoring;
nw_score_matrix(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), y.end(), std::move(score_function));
```

Otherwise, there are too many conversions for the compiler to figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: I see, is this because even though P has a default type the compiler is trying to deduce P from score_function, failing (because return types aren't part of a function signature?) and ignoring the default?

Answer (score 3):

A brief of explanation. When you write:

```
template <typename P = int>
void f(std::function<P()>) {}
```

then `P` is still in a deduced context, meaning the compiler will try to deduce `P` based on the type of an argument expression, ignoring the default value (`int`). However, type deduction only *deduces* types, i.e., the type of the argument expression must match the type of the corresponding parameter, so that the compiler will deduce the *missing* type template parameters.

So, once you call the function like below:

```
std::function<float()> a;
f(a);
```

the compiler will substitute `P` with `float`.

Now, if you wanted to pass in e.g. an address of a function:

```
char foo() { return {}; }
f(&foo);
```

the compiler will complain that it can't deduce `P`, because:

1. It is still in a deduced context.
2. The type of the argument (`char(*)()`) does not match the type of the parameter `std::function<P()>`.

That is, the compiler doesn't know that `P` from the signature of a `std::function<P()>` should be matched against the return type of a function pointer, `char`.

You could, say, force the type explicitly:

```
f<char>(&foo);
```

but that isn't very flexible.

You could also put `std::function` in a non-deduced context, and let `P` be deduced elsewhere:

```
template <typename T> struct identity { using type = T; };

template <typename P>
void f(typename identity<std::function<P()>>::type, P c) {}

f(&foo, 'a'); // P will be deduced from the 'a' argument
```

But this won't work if `c` is defaulted and not specified in a function call arguments list.

Nothing stops you from deducing the exact type of the argument expression:

```
template <typename F>
void f(F&& f) {}

f(&foo);
```

If you care, you can always check if whatever `f` returns is convertible to `P`, or just read that type.

In your scenario, an instance of a completely unrelated type (`plus_minus_one`) is passed as an instance of `std::function`, so clearly, deduction fails. The compiler doesn't know that it has to look at its `operator()`, and use its defaulted return type.

`std::function` itself is a type-eraser, in your case you don't really need to erase any type.

Answer (score 1):

Using the suggestion provided by Piotr Skotnicki, I obtained the following possible solution for you. You want C++ to deduce the type of `score_function` itself, rather than the nested type of it. However, once you have that type - let's call it `F`, then you can manually retrieve what you need.

This helper trait struct extracts `P` from your code for given functional type `F` (that's basically Piotr Skitnicki's comment)

```
template<typename F, typename I>
struct PP {
    typedef typename std::decay<typename std::result_of<
      F(typename std::iterator_traits<I>::value_type,
        typename std::iterator_traits<I>::value_type)
      >::type>::type type;
};
```

Now, with this help you can define your function as:

```
template<typename I, typename F>
   std::vector<std::vector<typename PP<F,I>::type>>
     nw_score_matrix(I xb, I xe, I yb, I ye,
                     F &&score_function,
                     typename PP<F,I>::type ID = -1,
                     typename PP<F,I>::type S = -1,
                     typename PP<F,I>::type M = 1)
   {
       typedef typename PP<F,I>::type P;

       ....... your existing code ......
   }
```

... and then you can call the function without any changes at the call site. In particular, you don't need to convert `matchScoring` to `std::function` object.

I believe it matches your requirement that `F` might be a functor, `std::function` or a lambda - it should work in all cases.

Comment: I think I see now, struct PP allows me to deduce the return type of F and I can use that rather than a template parameter P. 

I need to think about how I want this designed a bit. Vaughn Cato's answer explained why my example wasn't compiling which is what I was originally after, but this let's me consider a different design option which I think may be better.